# Tie into .NET from MS Access

Tags: .net, ms-access, crystal-reports, vba, ms-access-2010

I currently have two programs - One in .NET and one in Access.  Using Crystal Reports I have created a report in .NET.  The problem I am having is I do not want to create a new report in Access so I am not maintaining the same report in two separate places.

**Is there a way to tie into the .NET and access the report that has already been created?**

I have Crystal Reports 13, MS Visual Studio 2010 (since Crystal Reports 13 is only supported on this as of now) and MS Access 2010.

I tried referencing the dll that contains my report, within access and I received an error Can't add a reference to the specified file.

I have also tried using a Shell command.

Any help on this issue would be appreciated.

Comment: Crystal Reports used to have an ActiveX control that could be used in "old fashioned" (pre-.NET) applications such as VB6 programs. Does it still ship with something like that? (I haven't really worked with CR for several years, so my memory is a bit fuzzy. I think the control was called CRAXDRT.DLL. I also heard talk that CR was planning to phase out their older controls and move toward just supporting .NET so the ActiveX control may not even be an option any more.)

Comment: Thank you.  I have read posts from 10 years ago that stated the "old fashioned" way was last supported in CR XI R2.  I also believe you are right and they have phased out the older controls, but I wasn't sure if SAP added and similar functionality back in.  Thanks for the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I have done in my scenario is created a console application in my .NET solution.  I have another project in my solution that contains my crystal report information.  I was able to use a shell command to pass the parameters from Access over to my .NET program.  I was able to generate my report (with the parameters passed from Access) with ease.